# Can OpenCV detect predefined image markers in still images

Tags: opencv, augmented-reality

I’m completely new to the world of opencv and I wanted to ask a conceptual question...

Is it possible to detect “markers” in still photos in a similar manner to how augmented reality frameworks detect and track marker images in a video feed?

If a single image contains a known marker (from a database of unique markers) can I extract the size, position and orientation of that marker (assuming that the marker image has sufficient detectable features etc)?

Comment: depends on the appearance of your markers and the quality of the images. You shouldn't start with capturing/recording images with any markers you thought of. Instead you should make sure that you are able to detect those markers, or redesign them. There are some general purpose markers like ARUCO markers or QR codes, but still you should test them with your setup (size, distance to camera, illuminance, etc...) before assuming wrong things.

Comment: Look here, it is using images for tracking all done with OpenCV https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx/tree/master/Source/ARX/OCVT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. One of the ways to do this is by using feature matching. In your case, you have predefined markers in the source image and it has to be matched with the target image as shown [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html). One change would be we don't need to find the key points in the source image. 
Suppose you have a set of markers (x1, y1), (x2, y2) .. , You can compute sift or orb descriptors like this.

```
key_points_src = [cv2.KeyPoint(x1, y1, 1), cv2.KeyPoint(x2, y2, 1) ...]
key_points_src, src_des = orb.compute(src_img, key_points_src)
```

Now to match them with the target image one way would be:
Find key points and compute descriptors in the target image

```
key_points_target, target_des = orb.detectAndCompute(target_img, None)
```

Now match them

```
bf = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(src_des,target_des)
```

This can be a starting point and checkout opencv [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/) for other methods like countours, template matching etc that can be used for marker based AR.